# How can I update Task status and the Actuals of a specific task?

Tags: java, rally

I am building a Android App using RallyRestApi. I want to update Task status and the Actuals of a specific task. How can I achieve that? Below is my code. I get a list of UserStories and tasks in a arrayList. I want to update task status/actuals of a specific task on the fly. What I have tried:

```
RallyRestApi restApi = new RallyRestApi(new URI("https://rally1.rallydev.com"),"********************************");
        SimpleDateFormat iso = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
        Date today = new Date();
        String today1 = iso.format(today);
QueryRequest us = new QueryRequest("HierarchicalRequirement");
            QueryFilter currentiteration = new QueryFilter("Iteration.StartDate","<=",today1);
            currentiteration = currentiteration.and(new QueryFilter("Iteration.EndDate",">=",today1));
            us.setQueryFilter(currentiteration);
            us.setFetch(new Fetch("Name", "FormattedID","Tasks"));
            JsonArray us1 = restApi.query(us).getResults();
            for(int i=0;i<us1.size();i++)
            {
                QueryRequest task = new QueryRequest((JsonObject) us1.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("Tasks"));
                task.setFetch(new Fetch("Name","Actuals","Estimate"));
                JsonArray tsk = restApi.query(task).getResults();
                for(int j=0;j<tsk.size();j++)
                {
                    System.out.println("UserStory : "+us1.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("Name")+tsk.get(j).getAsJsonObject().get("Name"));
                }
            }
```

[image]

I have got cards to show the user story/task and a circular controller to set the actuals against the estimates.When I swipe up the card the status has to be changed to complete.So I just need to update 2 values actuals and the status of the task

Just guide me through the java code i.e. how should I go with create Request/Create Response. I can pull it off in the App. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems fairly inefficient to query through all the stories and then load all their tasks in search of a specific one.  Do you have its FormattedID?  I'd probably just do simple task query to find the one task and then update it.

```
//Find task first
QueryRequest task = new QueryRequest("Task");
task.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("FormattedID","=","T1234");
task.setProject("/project/12345"); //make sure searching in correct project
JsonArray taskResult = restApi.query(task).getResults().get(0).getAsJsonObject();

//Update task
JsonObject updatedValues = new JsonObject();
updatedValues.addProperty("Actuals", 5.0);
UpdateRequest taskUpdate = new UpdateRequest(task.get("_ref").getAsString(), updatedValues);
restApi.update(taskUpdate);
```

There are some nice examples of using the toolkit in the docs here: https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForJava/wiki/User-Guide#examples

Comment: I want the entire tasks in the current iteration, that's why I queried in the above way.I have cards to show the user story and task.See my edit.

Comment: ok, cool.  well then you should be able to just take the update part from above, and skip the first part.  also, you can query for Tasks by Iteration directly without going through stories first.  Just make sure you fetch WorkProduct and you should get the story info you need...

Comment: Thanks a ton..My app is ready now and has gone for testing..thanks for all your help..

Comment: If in future you consider changing/updating for mobile support I have implemented it for android on a http-android library.I can share my code if you want